# Update third party component dlls in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reference, projects-and-solutions

I have a big solution with a lot of projects using some third party components (Infragistics).

Now, I installed a new version of that component (6=>7), in parallel with the old one.

Now I want that all my referenced third party dll's "point" to the newly installed version, but not sure if I should manually open each project, remove the old, and reset the references to the new path... there is really a lot of projects in the solution... is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infragistics provide a tool called "[Project Upgrade Utility](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2010.1/CLR3.5/html/Web_Using_the_Project_Upgrade_Utility_Programs_Menu.html)" that does precisely what you want.

All you have to do is start the app and select a solution file (.sln) or a project (.vbproj or .csproj) file, the app let you select to what version of infragistics you want to upgrade and it will do the rest of the job.

I used this method in numerous occasions to upgrade to the new releases of infragistics and it works without problems, and if the tool finds any problem it creates a report.

Remember that every infragistics dll has a line on the corresponding licences.licx file of the project with information regarding version, culture and public key, so if you go for a manual update you must update these lines too.

Comment: yeah, see my comment to Olaf... Even if I had 373 errors after this "upgrade"... I see the light in the end of the tunnel...

Comment: it throws me "NullReferenceException" for some projects... (((

Answer (score 1):

I usually use notepad++ to search and replace in all `.csproj` files. I assume the replace in files in Visual Studio will work good too.

Comment: this should work... if you know what with what replace... references have version, public key name... and if is the only one is less or more hard, but if you have multiple references, like grids, textboxes, shared dlls, win dlls...

Comment: If I recall correctly the Infragistics controls have the same public key etc, you only need to replace the path-part of the references.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Version Upgrade Utility" or "Version Utility" ([info here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.2/CLR2.0/html/Win_Using_The_Version_Utility.html)) by Infragistics.

Other 3rd party vendors (like DevExpress) have similar tools. You might wish to check those first.

Comment: very good point. Even if I didn't found "Version Utility", I found a "Project Upgrade Utility", dragged the solution folder and... Evrica! - it loaded all my projects... Say, this "thing" trowed some errors, but I hope I'll manage this...

Comment: Yes, there are different names for that tool. I thought "Project Upgrade Utility" was an older one, so I didn't mention it.
These tools used to be buggy, but I think not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it, but [this VS extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/baa11829-8471-4201-b45a-8afe7c30545d) seems like it might do the job

Comment: I installed and tried... didn't help, or I don't understand how it works... Thank you, however